# GROUP BY CUBE for partial columns

Tags: group-by, hive

Is it possible to reproduce grouping like this:

`GROUP BY a, b, CUBE(c,  d, e);`

to some structure valid for Hive QL? (using `WITH CUBE` or smth else)

Have no idea how to combine `WITH CUBE`, because looks like i cant use it for part of columns in `GROUP BY` clause

Try to solve grouping problem